# Problema com o relacionamento na Tabela Mãe (Herança) no PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, herança, modelo-relacional

Eu tenho a Tabela Mãe Pagamento:

```
CREATE TABLE pagamento
(
  pagcod serial not null,      
  CONSTRAINT pk_pag PRIMARY KEY (pagcod)
)
```

E as duas tabelas filhas Dinheiro e Cartão de Crédito:

```
CREATE TABLE dinheiro
(
  desconto numeric(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  juros numeric(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00
)inherits(pagamento); 

CREATE TABLE cartao_credito
(
  num_cartao integer NOT NULL,
  datavalidade date NOT NULL,
  senha character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  agencia integer NOT NULL,
  titular character varying(200) NOT NULL
)inherits(pagamento);
```

Quando eu vou dar o INSERT na tabela DINHEIRO por exemplo o atributo PAGCOD da tabela mãe PAGAMENTO vem automaticamente:

```
INSERT INTO dinheiro(pagcod, desconto, juros)VALUES (4, 100.00, 12.5);
```

Dando um SELECT * FROM DINHERIO A PK aparece normalmente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim como dando um SELECT * FROM PAGAMENTO a PK também aparece normalmente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PROBLEMA: Quando eu vou tentar referencia esta pk de pagamento na tabela PEDIDO:

```
CREATE TABLE pedido
(
  pedcod serial not null,
  peddata date NOT NULL ,
  ped_num_notafiscal integer NOT NULL,
  pedstatus varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ABERTO',
  ped_funcinario integer NOT NULL,
  ped_cliete integer NOT NULL,
  ped_pagamento integer,
  CONSTRAINT pk_pedido PRIMARY KEY (pedcod),
  CONSTRAINT fk_cliente FOREIGN KEY (ped_cliete)REFERENCES cliente (clicod),
  CONSTRAINT fk_funcionario FOREIGN KEY (ped_funcinario)REFERENCES funcionario (funcod),
  CONSTRAINT fk_pagamento FOREIGN KEY (ped_pagamento)REFERENCES pagamento (pagcod)  
);
```

Aparece o seguinte erro: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como resolver este problema? A PK aparece na tabela PAGAMENTO, porém quando vou tentá-la referenciá-la na tabela PEDIDO dar este erro. 
A sintaxe do INSERT do PEDIDO:

```
INSERT INTO public.pedido(pedcod, peddata, ped_num_notafiscal, pedstatus, ped_funcinario, ped_cliete, ped_pagamento)
    VALUES (7, '02-11-2017', 2323, 1, 1, 1, 4);
```

Comment: coloca a sintaxe do insert por favor

Comment: Coloquei o insert do pedido, a última coluna que eu tento relacionar ao Pagamento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lendo a documentação: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS

Encontrei que:

> Outros tipos de restrições (chave única, chave primária e restrições de chaves estrangeiras) não são herdados.

e

> Uma limitação séria do recurso de herança é que os índices (incluindo restrições exclusivas) e as restrições de chave externa aplicam-se apenas a tabelas individuais, e não às suas heranças. Isso é verdade tanto nos lados referenciados como referenciados de uma restrição de chave estrangeira.

Ou seja, esse comportamento é esperado pelo postgresql, você não pode usar herança entre tabelas junto de chaves estrangeiras.

Você pode remover a `CONSTRAINT fk_pagamento` e talvez fazer essa verificação por trigger.

Reproduzi a situação no SQLFiddle:

Com a `CONSTRAINT fk_pagamento` (ERRO): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cd38b/2

Sem a `CONSTRAINT fk_pagamento`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/491475/2

Answer (score 0):

A restrição faz uma busca apenas nos registros diretamente vinculados a tabela pagamento, algo semelhante a FROM ONLY, e como os registros foram incluídos nas tabelas descendentes (dinheiro e cartao_credito), não existindo então registros exclusivamente adicionados em sua tabela referenciada na chave estrangeira.
Ainda não foi implementada uma integridade que faça a busca nas tabelas herdadas que tenha sido aceita a integridade entre os relacionamentos.